# Contain a sprite node within the screen/view

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, collision, skspritenode

I have a sprite node which moves left to right with user touch. 
However currently it will exit the screen, I want to add a node either side so if the sprite node touches the node on either side it hugs it and remains there until user touch to make it travel the opposite direction.

This is what I thought of doing but it isn't working currently.

```
    let shipTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "ship.png")
    ship = SKSpriteNode(texture: shipTexture)
    ship.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)
    ship.zPosition = 3
    ship.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: 30, height: 100))
    ship.physicsBody!.isDynamic = true
    ship.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0b1
    ship.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 0b1
    ship.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = 0b1
    ship.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    self.addChild(ship)



    let side = SKNode()
    side.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.midY)

    side.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: CGRect(x: -240, y: -160, width: 480, height: 320))

    side.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false
    side.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0b1
    side.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 0b1
    side.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = 0b1

    self.addChild(side)

    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        print("Collision")
    }
}

//var moveLeft = SKAction.moveBy(x: 800, y: 0, duration: 2)
//frame.size.width




override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {




    ship.removeAllActions()

    switch direction ?? .left {
    case .left:
        ship.run(SKAction.moveBy(x: -frame.size.width, y: 0, duration: 3))
    case .right:
        ship.run(SKAction.moveBy(x: frame.size.width, y: 0, duration: 3))
    }

    direction = direction == nil || direction == .right ? .left : .right
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. The reason is - you use action to move your node, but should use physics - force and impulse

Try this one:

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

var ship = SKSpriteNode()
var bg = SKSpriteNode()

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {


    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {


        let bgTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "bg.png")
        let moveBGanimation = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -bgTexture.size().height), duration: 4)
        let shiftBGAnimation = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: bgTexture.size().height), duration: 0)
        let moveBGForever = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([moveBGanimation, shiftBGAnimation]))

        var i: CGFloat = 0

        while i < 3 {

            bg = SKSpriteNode(texture: bgTexture)
            bg.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: bgTexture.size().height * i)
            bg.size.width = self.frame.width

            bg.run(moveBGForever)
            self.addChild(bg)

            i += 1

        }

        let shipTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "ship.png")
        ship = SKSpriteNode(texture: shipTexture)
        ship.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)
        ship.zPosition = 3
        ship.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: 30, height: 100))
        ship.physicsBody!.isDynamic = true
        ship.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0b1
        ship.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 0b1
        ship.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = 0b1
        ship.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        self.addChild(ship)

        let side = SKNode()
        side.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        side.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: CGRect(x: -self.frame.width/2, y: -self.frame.height/2, width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height))

        side.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false
        side.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0b1
        side.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 0b1
        side.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = 0b1

        self.addChild(side)

        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

        func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
            print("Collision")
        }

    }

    //var moveLeft = SKAction.moveBy(x: 800, y: 0, duration: 2)
    //frame.size.width

    enum Direction: Int {
        case left = 0
        case right
    }

    var direction: Direction?

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {




        ship.removeAllActions()

        switch direction ?? .left {
        case .left:
            ship.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: -20, dy: 0))
            //ship.run(SKAction.moveBy(x: -frame.size.width, y: 0, duration: 3))
        case .right:
            ship.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 20, dy: 0))
            //ship.run(SKAction.moveBy(x: frame.size.width, y: 0, duration: 3))
        }

        direction = direction == nil || direction == .right ? .left : .right
    }




    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {



    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {


    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't working for some reason. Does anything else need adding? Have I correctly added the node to the right side?

Comment: Make sure that you also set same `CategoryBitMask` for moth nodes

Comment: I'm definitely going wrong somewhere. They're all set at 0b1 for both the ship and the side. Is the position for the side correct as being the right hand edge of the view?

Comment: I've included the full code in my original post if that helps

Comment: So your ship is moving correct and all the problem is that there no any reaction for the collision, right?

Comment: Ship moves from left to right with touch however it is still exiting the screen

Comment: In my playground it look like you add `side` not correct. If you need limit all screen edges you better use `SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom`:

`side.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: CGRect(x: -240, y: -160, width: 480, height: 320))`

Comment: I've added in  side.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: CGRect(x: -240, y: -160, width: 480, height: 320)) however this isn't doing anything.

Comment: Try to run my update code in the playground. It works properly and object doesn't go out of the screen

Comment: I've altered the code however left the playground out as I'm getting errors. However it's still not working. Is the playground part vital?

Comment: The complete full code of the gameScene is now included in my post, what do you think?

Comment: No, it's not vital for sure. But really strange that after all these changes you still have no expected result.
Key changes:
- side & ship `collisionBitMask`, `contactTestBitMask` are the same.
- ship is dynamic
- side physics body is around the scene `edgeLoopFrom`

Comment: Also if you want use `SKPhysicsContactDelegate` you should set contact delegate - `self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self` and implement `func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact)`

Comment: Awesome Anton!! You cracked it. I just need to play around to get the movement back how it was but that should be a breeze.